# Display text above list if list is empty? (SharePoint 2007)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have seen a SharePoint list (Custom list) where a text shows up, whenever a list is empty (only for some views). E.g. to inform users of the guidelines for the list.

How can this be setup? I can't seem to find where this has been set...

Comment: You can edit it in data view properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't configurable within SharePoint by the end user. However if you have developer knowledge or a developer that can do this for you, there are various options such as jQuery. Please ask your question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you'd like a developer solution.

Comment: I AM a developer som no problem asking for a developer solution. Just wondered if there were a administrative solution e.g. Configuration

Comment: Seems like this can be configured in SharePoint Designer. Don't know if that topic belongs here, but I'll close this question :o)